# Data Generation Plan error

Tags: visual-studio, data-generation

When I attempt to run the data generation plan I get the following error, but there are no columns to be deleted.

The column XXXXX has been deleted and was previously selected for data generation.

Any help on this error would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: SQL is a language, not an RDBMS. With more than one product with SQL in the name, it would be really cool if people stopped tagging questions with SQL, when they mean mySql or SQL Server, which, BTW have tags of their own.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for Database Pros 2005

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered this error, but it seems that this is what happened:

1. A Data Generation Plan was created that included column XXXXX
2. Column XXXXX was deleted
3. You are now trying to run the plan again.

To fix it, either:

1. Put back the column in the table from whence it came, or
2. Take out the column from the plan.

Hope that helps!